# Where is the .targets file, and if it supported by .net core

Tags: visual-studio-2017, .net-core, nuget

I have a custom nuget package, which including a `.targets` file in the `\build` folder. When I install it to the .net framework project, after installation, we could see following import list in the project file:

```
<Import Project="..\packages\xxxx\build\xxxx.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\xxxx\build\xxxx.targets')" />
```

But when I install it to the .net core project, I could not find this import list in the project file, where I can find my `.targets` file, if it supported by .net core?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where is the .targets file, and if it supported by .net core

The `.targets` file is contained in the `project.assets.json` file in the obj folder, you can check the `project.assets.json` file, then you can get following code:

```
  "xxxx/1.0.0.0": {
    "type": "package",
    "build": {
      "build/xxxx.targets": {}
    }
  },
```

And this `.targets` file is also supported by the .net core project. As test, I have create a test `.targets` file in the nuget package like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="Test" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Message Text="This is Test Sample!"></Message>
  </Target> 
</Project>
```

After install this nuget package to the .net core project, then build the project I could get the output windows with messages "`This is Test Sample!`"

Answer (score 1):

For a project that uses PackageReferences the Imports can be found in two files:

- obj/ProjectName.nuget.g.props
- obj/ProjectName.nuget.g.targets

With ProjectName replaced with the name of your project.

For example, a .NET Standard project that uses Xamarin.Forms will have a .nuget.g.targets file that looks similar to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MSBuildAllProjects>$(MSBuildAllProjects);$(MSBuildThisFileFullPath)</MSBuildAllProjects>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ImportGroup Condition=" '$(ExcludeRestorePackageImports)' != 'true' ">
    <Import Project="$(NuGetPackageRoot)xamarin.forms/3.0.0.482510/build/netstandard2.0/Xamarin.Forms.targets" Condition="Exists('$(NuGetPackageRoot)xamarin.forms/3.0.0.482510/build/netstandard2.0/Xamarin.Forms.targets')" />
    <Import Project="$(NuGetPackageRoot)netstandard.library/2.0.1/build/netstandard2.0/NETStandard.Library.targets" Condition="Exists('$(NuGetPackageRoot)netstandard.library/2.0.1/build/netstandard2.0/NETStandard.Library.targets')" />
  </ImportGroup>
</Project>
```

The .nuget.g.props file will have Imports for any .props file that the NuGet package you are using contains.